# How can I called fragment from Custom View

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to call **Fragment** from custom `View` class But my code is not working :

```
public class Footer extends RelativeLayout implements View.OnClickListener {
  private Context context = null;

  private ImageView submitButton = null;

  private ImageView searchButton = null;    

  private ImageView closeButton = null;

  public Footer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    initialize(context);
  }

  private void initialize(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, this);
    ImageView imgFB = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    imgFB.setOnClickListener(this);
  } 

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.camera:
      selectImage();
      break;
    case R.id.submit:
      Fragment fragment = new AddProductFragment();
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragment.getFragmentManager();
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
      break;
    }
  }

  private void selectImage() {
    Dialog cameraDialog = new Dialog(context);
    cameraDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    cameraDialog.setContentView(R.layout.camera_popup);
    submitButton = (ImageView) cameraDialog.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    searchButton = (ImageView) cameraDialog.findViewById(R.id.seacrh);
    closeButton = (ImageView) cameraDialog.findViewById(R.id.close);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    cameraDialog.show();
  }
}
```

Why this code is not working? May be I am doing something wrong here. How can I call fragment from Custom `View`?

We can easily call **Fragment** by **getActivity()** method. But In this class I don't have **getActivity()** method that's why I am unable to use **getActivity()**

Comment: you should define a callback in this situation

Comment: @Amir Can you please elaborate more. Because I don't have idea in this scenario.

Comment: Sure , let me post some piece of code for you

Comment: What do you mean by saying not working? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` is a view. It must exist in some `activity` or `fragment`. It does not make architectural sense to handle `fragment` swapping from inside a view which should exist inside a fragment.

Create a new `FragmentActivity` (or just Activity) and use your view in it either in an xml file or created programmatically. Put the `onlickListener` etc. in the `Activity` not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's not proper way to call **Fragment** from Views so in this situation you can create a **Callback** ( in my case it's **OnBackListener**) interface like following :

```
public class EmptyPage extends FrameLayout {

    private View mRootLayout;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private TextView mDescription;
    private TextView mIcon;

    private OnBackClickListener onBackClickListener;

    public interface OnBackClickListener {
        public void onBackClick();
    }


    public EmptyPage(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(null);
    }

    public EmptyPage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(attrs);
    }

    public EmptyPage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {

        mRootLayout = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.include_empty_page, null);
        mTitle = (TextView) mRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_warning);
        mIcon = (TextView) mRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.icon_warning);
        mDescription = (TextView) mRootLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_warning_hint);


        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray attributes = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EmptyPage);

            String text = attributes.getString(R.styleable.EmptyPage_android_text);
            if (text != null)
                mTitle.setText(text);

            attributes.recycle();
        }

        //put your clickable items here
        mRootLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onBackClickListener != null) {
                    onBackClickListener.onBackClick();
                }
            }
        });
        addView(mRootLayout);
    }
}
```

Then put onClickListener on your item you want. ( in my case I want to whole view be clickable so I put it in **mRootLayout** )

Then in your Activity/Fragment you should do something like this :

```
mEmptyPage = (EmptyPage) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ep_empty_view);
        mEmptyPage.setOnBackClickListener(new EmptyPage.OnBackClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackClick() {

                //Open new FRAGMENT HERE 

            }
        });
```

It's done. when you click on View **OnBackClick** called and you can open your fragment without any exception.

P.S : if you need more Item to be clickable you just to need add another method to your interface ( e.g add **onBackClick2** )

Answer (score -1):

user this function to call any fragment

**R.id.linearLayoutDataContent** is a contener for fragment

```
public void showFragmentInContener(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.linearLayoutDataContent, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Got exception here getFragmentManager(). The method getFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Footer

Comment: pass the activity as a parameter and use that activity.getFragmentManager().